# Error With creating an excel file from java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi I would like to create an excel file from a java code, I put this code on eclipse but nothing happen

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TestPOI1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         //create the new workbook
         Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

         try {
                 //create the output stream to save the document on the hard drive
                 FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test1.xls");

                 //write the file onto the hard drive
                 workbook.write(output);

                 //finish it up by closing the document
                 output.close();
         } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }   
    }        
}
```

in the console, this message is written

```
 Usage: BiffDrawingToXml [options] inputWorkbook Options:
 -exclude-workbook exclude workbook-level records
 -sheet-indexes output sheets with specified indexes
 -sheet-namek output sheets with specified name
```

and I can't found my excel file in the hard drive or in the file project. thanks for help.

Comment: Are you totally sure that this output belongs to this program?

Comment: Dnt think the above code will throw any such error

Comment: First refresh ur project in Eclipse then you can see it.. in the console there will be nothing .if you run this program

Comment: Looks like you're running a different program!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error you will get while the Jar is still building. Just wait for few seconds.
**Right Click** and then **Run** : It will work..!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).